# Call R from Matlab for Mac

Tags: r, macos, matlab, path

I have been given a script in Matlab that calls R to do some of the calculations.

The first line of the script is:

```
pthR='C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin';
```

This works fine on my Windows VM but as a Mac user I want to be able to run the script natively.

R is installed in Applications but changing the path to:

```
pthR='/Applications/R';
```

Gives "ERROR: invalid R path"

What is the correct path to R for a Mac? 
Is there a line of code that I can type in R to find out?

Comment: Swapping in:
/usr/local/bin/R
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
has no effect

Comment: Start R and from the R console enter `commandArgs()` and R will display the command that started R up.

Comment: in mac console do `which R` it should give you right path for R.